# How do I integrate photo uploading with the tinymce content editor in a Rails3.1 app?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, tinymce, asset-pipeline

I am using the tinymce-rails gem which is working great on it's own. I want to create a custom plugin for it so I can use paperclip to upload images to a media library. I need to access the tinymce directory so I can add my custom plugin code, I just don't know where the gem is putting it. I am not completely sure where the asset pipeline loads files from(where does jquery live? for example). I know that it concatenates the files from the app/assets/javascripts directory, but that directory only contains the application.js file. Anyone know of a solution for this. Maybe I don't even need to create a custom plugin.

Answer (score 1):

Plugins (custom and regular ones) are usually to be found under `tiny_mce/plugins/pluginname/editor.js`. I am not familiar with tinymce-rail gem, but you could for example search for "contextmenu" (a regular plugin) and you will find the directory containing the others if the directory is another than the one in the regular shipped tinymce version.